# How to turn a directory into a hidden directory

Tags: linux, bash, git-bash

I have a directory /f/ssh which I would like to turn into /f/.ssh. I'm working with git-bash on win7  I've tried:

```
/f
$ mv /ssh /.ssh
mv: cannot stat `/ssh': No such file or directory    

/f
$ mv ssh .ssh  
mv: cannot move `ssh' to `.ssh/ssh'
```

But its not working. How can I make this happen ?

Comment: Do you have rights on that directory?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Linux if it's on Windows 7?

Comment: @Jay: No probably needed.  He told us it is git-bash, not cygwin bash.  The [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-bash/info) explains what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want your second example (current working directory) and not root (/).

```
$ mv ssh .ssh  
mv: cannot move `ssh' to `.ssh/ssh'
```

What this is saying is there is ***already a folder called ".ssh" in your current working directory.***

By calling that command again it's also saying you don't have access to move "ssh" into the ***already existing*** ".ssh" folder.

Try an `ls -al` to list all current files/folders in the directory, including hidden.

Comment: Sorry you were right - there was already an .ssh file. Thanks for the explanation